# Mongodb java driver: mongojack , query by subdocument id

Tags: java, mongodb

Can anyone help me in writing the equivalent query for criteria on mongodb subdocument using mongojack java driver

db.parentdocs.find({"subdoc._id" : ObjectId("542d916a18ee9cfa2daeae15")})

Here subdoc is a subdocument inside parentdoc document. I am able to query using other attributes but not using id like

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("subdoc.name":"mysubdoc");

I need to write the java equivalent of above find query(db.parentdocs.find({"subdoc._id" : ObjectId("542d916a18ee9cfa2daeae15")})).

Comment: Can any one help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectId` is a special type in MongoDB driver (`org.bson.types.ObjectId`); therefore, you need to add it to your query as:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("subdoc._id", new ObjectId("542d916a18ee9cfa2daeae15"));
```